# Setting Default Button in Ajaxified Wizard Control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, wizard

I have a Wizard control on my ASP.NET web form.  I am setting the default button on each step in the ApplicationWizard PreRender event in code-behind like so:

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = ApplicationWizard.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("StepNextButton").UniqueID;
```

This is working perfectly, but when I ajaxify the Wizard control it does not work.  The Default button is set to the Control I specify when initally loading the form (StartNextButton) but does not update to StepNextButton on other steps.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After a day or two of pulling my hair out I managed to crack this...  hope this helps others as frustrated as I was:

Anyone that has found this post knows that the intuitive answer here, setting the default button of the form to the Next button of your Wizard, does nothing.  So, the next logical step is to try and design around the problem by clicking the button on behalf of the user.  Assume I've attached the below handler to my textbox from within the codebehind and that myButtonId is the id of the button I need as my default:

```
            function textKeyDown(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    var myBtn = $get(myButtonId);
                    myBtn.click();
                }
            }
```

You would think the above would work just fine, but as it turns out, forcing the Wizard button to click was creating an extremely sneaky conflict - the first button on the page would click as well, overriding the initial button click I forced via script and creating very strange results.  In my case, the first button in my master page is a button that says Home, and when the user clicks it, they go back to their home page.  So in my attempts to force the Wizard's Next button to click I would end up right back at my homepage for what looked like no reason at all.  After attaching to PageRequestManager.initializeRequest I was able to see I had two seperate postbacks initiating:  1 for my forced wizard button click, and 1 for a button that wasn't even on my radar at the time - the home page button.

So, long story short, if I update the form's Default Button (Page.Form.DefaultButton) from within the code behind, then emit this script from within the code behind and reference it from my textbox as well, all works just fine:

```
    public static void ExampleAssignDefaultButton(WizardStepBase activeWizardStep, TextBox myTextBox, IButtonControl myButton)
    {
        // create the format string for the script
        string javaScript = @"function defaultButton(src, evt){{
                                if(evt.keyCode == 13){{
                                    var btn = $get('{0}');
                                    setTimeout(new function() {{ btn.click(); }}, 5);
                                }}
                            }}";

        // format it ...
        javaScript = String.Format(javaScript, ((WebControl)myButton).ClientID);
        // register it...
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(activeWizardStep, activeWizardStep.GetType(), "defaultButton", javaScript, true);

        // assign it to my textbox
        myTextBox.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "defaultButton(this, event);");

        // also update the form's default button:
        myTextBox.Page.Form.DefaultButton = ((WebControl)myButton).UniqueID;
    }
```

It is worth noting that I always call the above method from the active wizard step's OnPreRender event.  It's also worth noting that, because I only have one textbox per step in my wizard, I only had to assign this behavior to a single control.  I have not attempted this fix scoped to catch the Enter key press across the whole page, though I can't imagine it'd behave too differently in that context.  You probably don't need to catch the Enter key on each control within your wizard if you have lots of inputs per step.

So, there you have it - only 12 hours of troubleshooting to do something that should have taken about 10 minutes.

Happy coding.

B

Comment: I have this problem. I'm trying to resolve based on your answer but just can't get it to work. The javascript is added ok but the page still responds to the homepage button rather than the next button....? any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Mad Pierre - have you tried on multiple browsers?  My answer here might be slightly out of date for browsers like Chrome that have decided "click()" can't be invoked and instead you have to simulate the mouse click by generating DOM2 events...

Comment: Not yet. I'm trying with IE(9) first. Did you see my other comment above re: the script working if I add an alert?

Comment: Hi @MadPierre - maybe disable your home button before the .click() call?  I'd have to see your code to know what exactly is going on but something is definitely triggering click on your other button and disabling the button will prevent click from being allowed to fire -- edit - just saw you fixed your issue - glad you nailed it :)  maybe disable will help someone else reading this thread so I'll leave this in tact...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Brian, your script helped me setting up my own when using RadAjax and multiple user controls and multiple types of panels. You can simplify the defaultButton by passing the button ID from the control and not in the script.

In page:

```
function defaultButton(btnid, src, evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
        var btn = $get(btnid);
        setTimeout(new function () { btn.click(); }, 5);
    }
}
```

In code:

```
Private Sub WizardStep_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles wsUserPass.PreRender, wsCompanyCode.PreRender, wsSetPassword.PreRender
    Dim button As WebControl = Nothing
    Dim activeWizardStep As WizardStepBase = CType(sender, WizardStepBase)
    Select Case activeWizardStep.StepType
        Case WizardStepType.Step
            button = activeWizardStep.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("StepNextButton")
        Case WizardStepType.Start
            button = activeWizardStep.FindControl("StartNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("StartNextButton")
        Case WizardStepType.Finish
            button = activeWizardStep.FindControl("FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("FinishButton")
    End Select
    If button Is Nothing Then Return
    Dim ctrls = FindControls(Of RadTextBox)(activeWizardStep)
    For Each ctrl In ctrls
        ctrl.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", String.Format("defaultButton('{0}', this, event);", button.ClientID))
    Next
    pnlMain.DefaultButton = button.UniqueID
End Sub

Public Shared Function FindControls(Of T)(ctrl As Control) As List(Of T)
    Dim controls As New List(Of T)
    If ctrl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
        For Each subctrl In ctrl.Controls
            If [Type].ReferenceEquals(GetType(T), subctrl.GetType()) Then
                controls.Add(subctrl)
            Else
                controls.AddRange(FindControls(Of T)(subctrl))
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return controls
End Function
```

(Note, UniqueID did not work for me, had to change it to ClientID)

Comment: This is a weird one! Having based my c# code on yours the default button works only if I have an alert at the end of the javascript function! ie. if I put

function defaultButton(btnid, src, evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
            var btn = $get(btnid);
            setTimeout(new function () { btn.click(); }, 5);
            alert('test');
        }
    } 

It works! However removing the alert('test') causes my default homepage button click to "win". Anyone got any ideas? This has wasted a couple of days for me so far.....

Answer (score 0):

Try the [ScriptManager.SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346807.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What is the definition of a default button? If it's a button, which should be called when you are in a text form field (input type=text) and press enter, then in every browser it is a first submit or image button in the form (input type=submit|image) if exist.

What you can do, is to add a client script to all controls, to which such rule as submit form on [enter] apply (like on input type="text").

Server side sample (can be used in Form_Init) just for an idea:

```
SomeTextBox.Attributes.Add("onkeydown",
    "if((event.keyCode&&event.keyCode==13)){" +
    Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(StepNextButton, "") +
    ";return false;}" +
    "if((event.keyCode&&event.keyCode==27)){" +
    Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(CancelButton, "") +
    ";return false;}");
```

keyCode==13 is an Enter key
keyCode==27 is an Escape key

Answer (score 0):

I think I've finally cracked this! The fact that a (debug) alert message in the javascript made it work pointed me in the right direction...

I had to add a couple of lines to the javascript to get it to work so that my method looks like this:

```
private void SetDefaultButtonScript(WizardStepBase activeWizardStep, IButtonControl myButton)
    {
        string clientID = ((WebControl)myButton).ClientID;
        string uniqueID = ((WebControl)myButton).UniqueID;

        // create the format string for the script 
        string javaScript = @"function defaultButton(btnid, evt) {{ 
                                if (evt.keyCode == 13) {{ 
                                    __doPostBack('{0}', '');
                                    var btn = $get('{1}');
                                    btn.focus();
                                    return;
                                }} 
                            }} 
                            ";
        javaScript = String.Format(javaScript, uniqueID, clientID); 

        // register it... 
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(activeWizardStep, activeWizardStep.GetType(), "defaultButton", javaScript, true);

        foreach (Control c in activeWizardStep.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)c).Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "defaultButton(this, event);"); 
            }
            //TODO child controls of controls to find all text boxes, any other controls etc
        }

        Page.Form.DefaultButton = uniqueID;
    }
```

I'm using __doPostBack instead of click too but that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any scripting here.  The problem seems to be that there are multiple submit buttons on the page.  So you have to tell asp.net which one you'd like to use as the "default" submit.  And you have to tell it at the right time in the page lifecycle.  I'm not sure if it's optimal, but doing it in the PreRender event seems to work.  A basic ajaxified wizard with only the following code added seems to use the proper button:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPreRender(e)
    Select Case LoginWizard.ActiveStep.StepType
        Case WizardStepType.Start
            Page.Form.DefaultButton = LoginWizard.FindControl("StartNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("NextStart").UniqueID
        Case WizardStepType.Step
            Page.Form.DefaultButton = LoginWizard.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("NextStep").UniqueID
        Case WizardStepType.Finish
            Page.Form.DefaultButton = LoginWizard.FindControl("FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("LastStep").UniqueID
    End Select
End Sub
```